# Execute ASyncTask from a Notification Action Button Press?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifications, http-post

I want to do an HTTPpost when a certain Notification Action button is pressed in my notification.

How do I go about doing this as the NotificationAction seems to only execute PendingIntents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications use PendingIntents because the notification happens in a different program.  In order to get back to the context of your application, you use a PendingIntent.

Do your HTTPPost from an IntentService (arguably where HTTPPosts should be done, under any conditions).  Fire the PendingIntent at the IntentService and Bob's your Uncle